# SYSTEM DATE as realtime entry to database

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to get the system date as Last Modified date in my Database, what will be the query I need to give in Oracle SQL Developer ?

Comment: You can use 'SYSDATE' where ever system date is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
current_date
```

or Use

```
TO_CHAR
```